# Multicolumn unique constraint for columns in different tables

Tags: database-design, unique-constraint

I require some input on a database design I am busy with.

To summarize what I am trying to model (please refer to the [database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGBb.png)).

Option 1:

- An entry in `File` may have one or more cost elements applied to it.
- A cost element has a Description, a Measure (currency or %) an Allocation (by mass, by volume, etc...) and a value (numeric).
- Multi-column uniqueness must be enforced on the combination of `FileID` and `CostDescriptionID`.
- **Pro**: Can create unique index to enforce data integrity on the above requirement.
- **Con**: Cost element combinations cannot be reused - data duplication.

Option 2:

- In order to reduce duplication of entries, `CostElement2` has been separated into three tables: `CostDefault`, `CostInput` and `CostElement`.
- **Pro**: CostInput allows for combinations of `CostDescriptionID`, `CostMeasureID` and `CostAllocationID` to be reused.
- **Pro**: `CostInput` allows for reuse of `CostElementID` and `ElementValue` combinations.
- **Con**: Not possible to enforce the multi-column unique constraint on the combination of `FileID` and `CostDescriptionID`.

Is there a better design decision that would allow me to get the best of both worlds?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding a Gw_ prefix to every single table? Perhaps a schema would be better? I personally detest prefixes like this. They add pointless typing and add nothing. They also make it harder to read the table names. And why the Gw in the middle of most of your column names? I would do something like CostDefaultID instead of IdGwCostDefault. And you should avoid reserved words for column names at all costs (timestamp, Value, Name, Description etc...) As for the question at hand...well I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. I did think to myself "vomit" when I read through the question before posting. I have taken your suggested naming changes on board. The reason for the Gw_ prefix is because I am adding these tables to an existing ERP database and the ERP recommended guidelines for adding custom tables is to prefix with a certain string. Also this helps to group the tables in the database. I have tried to reword the question and hope that it's now clear what I am asking. If you would be kind enough to comment. Thanks.

Comment: I would ignore that documentation. That is not a great suggestion. Instead of bizarre prefixes creating a new schema would be much better. It will still group like items in object explorer but you don't have to wrestle with absurd names. I truly don't fully understand your question but option 2 sounds like it is closer to what you want. Option 1 looks like a denormalized design that will cause lots of pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest sticking with option 1, the single table. In this case, I would not consider the column combinations a re-use requiring further normalization.

You may want to create simply create a compound primary key on `FileID` and `CostElementID` in that order.

My only comment on naming is I'm uncomfortable with a table with the name "`File`". Other than that, you seem fine.